# Codeigniter Loader timeout expired

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, codeigniter

I'm trying to deploy my website to a webserver. The website is created using CodeIgniter with a PostgreSQL database in a different server. I already installed PHP 5.6, httpd, php-pgsql. I keep getting this error and I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired
Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 305
```

It works fine on my laptop with xampp, and I never messed with the Loader.php file. Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem may be that PostgreSQL is not runnig well try to restart it and look at your log file if there is some errors ?

Comment: it's hard to help without seeing the code...

Answer (score 0):

found it.. so my website grabs the host address of the website and database from the constants.php in config, and I thought that I had changed it into the web server and database addresses.. turns out I hadn't..